# Playing mp3 Audio files in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio, streaming, mp3

I want to stream an audio from server using windows phone 7

the audio extension is mp3. I have tried Mp3MediaStreamSource class but the problem was that it downloads all the audio then start playing it.

I want to know what is the best way to play audio in WP7 for platform 7.0 ( with buffering -> not waiting until the entire audio file is downloaded.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Background Audio agent do stream mp3 radio broadcast. Take a look at this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202978(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: No, only for 7.1 and 7.1.1. But if you want to have you app in the Marketplace, you can developr for 7.1. User with 7.0 cannot download apps from Marketplace anymore